# Save remote img-file to server, with php

Tags: php, save

I want to save a remote img-file to my server, but I don't know how to do.

The image url is `http://img.youtube.com/vi/Rz8KW4Tveps/1.jpg` and `1.jpg` is to be saved and renamed to `imgfolder/imgID.jpg`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents()` to load the remote image to a binary string inside your PHP script (file access in PHP often accepts URLs to access remote resources - this is very handy), then store that file somewhere where you have write access. Here is a very simple example:

```
$image = file_get_contents("http://img.youtube.com/vi/Rz8KW4Tveps/1.jpg");
file_put_contents("imgfolder/imgID.jpg", $image);
```

Tada!

Comment: It works fine for me, i have a query. What if someone wants to grab pictures not ending with any extension like public pics in facebook. Regards

Comment: It should work the same: the file wrappers don't care about the "extension" not even about the MIME content type in the HTTP header - it just gets the binary data from the location you specify.

Answer (score 22):

If the URL stream wrappers are allowed, you can do it in 1 line rather than having to load it into a var:

```
copy('http://img.youtube.com/vi/Rz8KW4Tveps/1.jpg', 'imgfolder/imgID.jpg');
```

This is much less likely to cause a problem with PHP running out of memory.